# How to Download Java and run a file on command line

Tags: java

I know this is SUPER basic. I am very new to all of this. I tried to download java and run a helloworld by following these instructions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

I got an error when I tried to use the "javac" command to compile. This is what appears in the command prompt:

C:\Users\USer18\Desktop>javac HelloWorldApp.java

'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Does this mean I downloaded java incorrectly? When I downloaded it, there were 3 different things to choose from, but I could only choose one, so I chose the first one. I tried to download java again and select the second one, but it said it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: You probably want to add the jdk to your path. Your machine can't locate the command because it has no idea where the executable actually is.

Answer (score 3):

From the tutorial you linked, it tells you to "consult the installation instructions" found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html

For Windows JDK, the instructions linked are here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDEBCCJ

The part you need to look for is "Updating the PATH Environment Variable"

> Updating the PATH Environment Variable
>
> If you do not set the PATH variable, you need to specify the full path
>   to the executable file every time you run it, such as:
>
> C:> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac" MyClass.java
>
> It is useful to set the PATH variable permanently so it will persist
>   after rebooting.
>
> To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the
>   jdk1.8.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path
>   looks something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. Set the PATH
>   variable as follows on Microsoft Windows:
>
> ```
> Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.
>
> Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.
>
> Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation to the PATH variable in System Variables. The following is a typical value
> ```
>
> for the PATH variable:
>
> ```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> ```
> The PATH environment variable is a series of directories separated by semicolons (;) and is not case-sensitive. Microsoft Windows looks
> ```
>
> for programs in the PATH directories in order, from left to right.
>
> ```
> You should only have one bin directory for a JDK in the path at a time. Those following the first instance are ignored.
>
> If you are not sure where to add the JDK path, append it.
>
> The new path takes effect in each new command window you open after setting the PATH variable.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When ever we execute any command, it is searched in the directory where we are current in or mentioned in `PATH` environment variable. The oly thing which you need is just add `<path of yourjdk>\bin` to `PATH`

**Windows 10 and Windows 8**

- In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

**Windows 7**

- From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
- Choose Properties from the context menu.
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.